# Is there a way to create a "safe" Navigator.popUntil function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

When you pop the navigator too many times in Flutter you are met with a black screen. To prevent that from ever happening to the user because of some unforeseen event on my part, I have created the following function:

```
  static void safePop<T extends Object>(BuildContext context, [T? result]) {
    if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop<T>(result);
    }
  }
```

That works great for simple pops, but I've recently migrated my app to using named routes and would like to use the Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName()) to more accurately pop widgets when I'm 4 or 5 pages into the app. I'm having trouble figuring out a way to implement something similar to above with popUntil.

Is there a way to prevent the Navigator from popping to a black screen in case of an incorrect/non-existent route being passed to the popUntil function?

Thanks

Comment: The problem with handling this condition is that as you have it there nothing will happen if you can't pop so you may go to production, and have buttons that do nothing if you click on them. 

I would actually avoid using this conditional because it does more harm than good. You should be able to tell with certainty the navigational structure of your screens. Or at lease add an else with `assert(false);` so that in dev you get some error.

You should also look into Navigator 2.0  

I leave this as a comment because I didn't answer your question.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but I would rather a certain button fail and do nothing (and allow the user to use other parts of the app) than pop to a black screen that prevents the user from interacting with the app.